# How to get the response time of calls made within an API with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I'm using J-meter to get response time for an API via HTTP request but this API internally few more api services. Now, i need the response time taken by these internal calls too.
Pls could anyone assist to get this one sorted via J-meter

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I can think of:-

Check on "Follow Redirect" and then use listener like "View Result tree" or "Simple Data Writer" to write the output in an XML format instead of CSV. There you can find the redirected URLs and response time.
But, XML creation will consumer a lot of resource and should be avoided.

Second, use post processor and fetch the response time from the sampler results along with redirected URL and write it in a csv. This requires some coding.