# How to capture the response time of calls to other APIs within an API with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am currently using Jmeter to test the response time for an API. Lets call it API A. If API A calls API B, which is hosted on the same server but different port, is there a way for me to capture the response time of API B using Jmeter?

I realize there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50404677/how-to-get-the-response-time-of-calls-made-within-an-api-with-jmeter) which is trying to accomplish the same thing but it does not work for me. I don't see the internal call to API B.

Comment: if possible add your tried code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could not. `Jmet` is an outsider, Jmet only know there is `API-A`, and doesn't know the internal implementation(that `API-A` calls `API-B`).

A better design would be, for each APIs, itself should metric the total run time and log into metric server. There's a lot of options about server side metrics system you could explore.

Comment: Thank you, I figured this was the case. We do have other ways of getting the metrics. We ended up just logging the response times of each API and compiling that data but was just hoping that jmeter could handle that too. Again thanks

Answer (score 1):

JMeter knows nothing about what's going on under the hood of your application, it sends a [HTTP Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods), waits for the response and measures the time taken as well as some other [metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html).

If there is some extra activity under the hood of an API call the only way to capture it is using a [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) or an [APM tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/apm-tools/) at the application under test end.